# quacamole javascript client http tunnel getting connected

Tags: guacamole

Guacamole 1.2.0

I have a running guac server and I want to create a client connection from another web app on different domain(for testing) and move to the same domain once production ready.  I've tried HTTPTunnel and the websockettunnel, both of failing for different reasons.  Websocket seems to only want to connect to itself on localhost even if I supply the full URL of the guac server and HTTP tunnel I'm getting a CORS error about InvalidAllowCredentials.  The following are two variations I've tried and the rest of the html is from the example on guac doc site.

```
var guac = new Guacamole.Client(
    new Guacamole.HTTPTunnel("https://example.com/tunnel", true)
    {#new Guacamole.WebSocketTunnel("https://example.com/websocket-tunnel", true)#}
);
```

If this connect was going to work I believe I'm missing configuration and authentication information.

The guac documentation seems to be lacking and I'm not sure what I should be doing.

What needs to be done to get connected to an existing machine?

Example.

API call, authenticate user and get a token.
API call, search for connection
Create tunnel, pass in connection somehow
Client connect

This should pop up the display to the remote machine.

Headers added in nginx config under the location / section

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' always;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, OPTIONS' always;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,ContentType,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With' always;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may check how a connection is made in the guacamole client application, in the file `ManagedClient.js`. Search for functions `getInstance()` and `getConnectString()`.

In principle, you are correct about the token, you can get one with this API call:

```
curl 'https://guacamole.example.com/guacamole/api/tokens' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data-raw 'username=guacadmin&password=somePassword'
```

The un/pw are for Guacamole, not for the remote machine.

Once you have the token, you may create `HTTPTunnel` and `Client`, populate parameters like shown in `getConnectString()` and initiate `connect()`. Keep in mind that the credentials for the remote machine are set up on the Guacamole side. In the `getConnectString()`, you are only selecting one of the connections defined on the Guacamole server.

Note that depending on the actual plugin used for authentication, different data may be sent; you can also make your own auth plugin with completely different authentication or make a plugin where remote machine credentials are sent directly from JS code. Several example auth plugins in the extensions directory; the above assumes you are using the default database auth plugin or file auth plugin.

Comment: For the time, I've dropped trying to have a deep integration so users don't know they're connecting to the guac server.

For now I'm opening the machines connection url directly in a new tab.  https://sourceforge.net/p/guacamole/discussion/1110834/thread/fb609070/#bec4.  {machineid}c{databasetype} e.g.  encode_base64("10cpostgresql").

If I get around to do doing a deeper integration I will reply back to this post in the future, thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

instead of this:
`{#new Guacamole.WebSocketTunnel("https://example.com/websocket-tunnel", true)#}`
use this:
`{#new Guacamole.WebSocketTunnel("ws://example.com/websocket-tunnel", true)#}`
or if you have ssl then `"wss"`

Comment: Please properly format the code in your answer to provide readability and improve understanding

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please elaborate on how your answer tries to answer the question and adds to existing content. See [answer] and [tour] for good tips